# How to authorize user for a subfolder

Tags: windows-server-2003, directory, authorization

Using Windows Server 2003, I would like to give a user full access to a subfolder. Let´s say I have folder A with subfolders B1 and B2. I observed that when granting authorization to B1, the user cannot access A. This is bad because user can´t reach B1. But if I grant authorization to A as well, the user can also access B2, which should not be allowed. I do not want to edit every folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set directory B1 and B2 so that they do not inherit their permissions from directory A.  Directory A will still require that the users have permissions to it so that they can see directories B1 and B2.

To do this, for each of B1 and B2, go to the `Security` tab in the directory properties, click the `Advanced` button and de-select `Allow inheritable permissions from the parent to propagate to this object and all child objects.`.  Set the required permissions for the directory then apply your changes.

You should now have all required users able to read from directory A, and only the desired users from directories B1 and B2.

Comment: Have I understood it right? I have to grant the user access to folder A so that he can see folder B1. To avoid the user being able to access B2, I have to forbid B2 to inherit permissions from A?

Comment: Yes.  If the user can't access directory A, they can't see that directories B1 / B2 exist - they will need at least `Read & Execute` permissions to directory A.  You could bypass the need to give permissions to directory A by sharing directories B1 / B2 and have the users access those shares directly, but for the scenario you describe that might not be an option for you.